# How do i after first 110 characters from database text, create link

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, substring

Im new to asp.net c#.

my question : i want to get the first 110 characters of a news text from my database and after 150 characters have been printed i want it to say "...Read more" which currently works.

however, i want the "...Read more" to be a link. any ideas?

my code behind.

```
protected string CutText(object text, int length)
{
    if (DBNull.Value == text || text == null) return "";
    string txt = text.ToString();
    if (txt.Length <= length) return txt;
    return txt.Substring(0, length) + "...Read more";
}
```

my Default.aspx code.

```
<p><%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"nyheder_tekst"), 110)%></p>
```

Comment: Why don't you cut the text already in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would remove the "...Read more" from the code behind and instead add it into the page directly as an anchor.

```
<p><%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"nyheder_tekst"), 110)%><a href="">...Read more</a></p>
```

Comment: It depends how you want the full article to display.  If it is as a separate page then you will need to create a new page for showing this, that takes some form of Id and looks up the article passed to it.